# evitar que json.load() convierta el texto en emojis

Tags: python, json, unicode

Tengo el siguiente archivo json:

```
{
"lupa": [
    "\ud83d\udd0e"
]
}
```

Y este código:

```
import json

with open('prueba.json',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    print(file)
    file = json.load(file,strict=False)
    
print(file)
```

El output es:

```
{'lupa': ['']}
```

Pero no quiero que convierta el código a emoji, quiero mantenerlo como está (*\ud83d\udd0e*).

¿Es posible?

Comment: ¿Quieres `lupa` contenga el string de caracteres "\ud83d\udd0e" (12 caracteres?
]

Comment: Sí, que al guardar el objeto leído en un nuevo archivo, se guarde con los caracteres y no con la lupa. No sé si eso tiene que ver con el print()

Comment: Probaste guardarlo? porque quizás es solo visual el problema y se guarda tal como tú lo quieres